# How to stop the ajax calls on typing in mass auto complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input type="text" ng-model="clientName" ng-mass-autocomplete-item="getClients">
```

Controller.js:

```
     $scope.getAgencies = {
                            suggest: suggest_Agencies,
                            debounce_suggest: 600,
                            debounce_blur: 500,
                            on_select: function (selected_item) {
                                $scope.agencyName = selected_item.value;
                            },
                        };
                        function suggest_Agencies(agencyName) {
                            $scope.agencies = [];
                            $scope.agencyName = agencyName;
                            var params = {"agencyName": agencyName};
                            ajaxcalls.ajaxPostRequest('catalog/getAgencies', params, function (response) {
                                var agencies = response.data;
                                if (agencies != null && agencies.length > 0) {
                                    agencies.forEach(function (item, index) {
                                        $scope.agencies.push({label: item.AgencyName, value: item.AgencyName});
                                    });
                                }
                            }, "noSpinner", false);
        /** here false argument means asynchronous set to false. */
                            return $scope.agencies;
                        }
```

Here is the [link](http://hakib.github.io/MassAutocomplete).

How can I resolve this? I want to achieve suggestions through this directive and stop ajax calls while typing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to help in Angular, but I think the idea would be to get all the agencies beforehand, set them to a master `agencies` list, then use MassAutocomplete to suggest based off that list, rather than doing `ajaxPostRequest` in `suggest` every time.

Comment: @J.Titus: this is quite an old question, just FYI. Don't let that stop you adding an answer, but the OP hasn't logged on for some time.

Comment: @halfer Ha! Didn't even realize that - completely missed the asked date. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No worries @J.Titus: it's an unfortunate side-effect of tidying up an old post - it gets pushed to the front page to ensure it has not been vandalised. I've asked at Meta to see if this can be stopped for trusted users, but it did not get any bites.